# Toolbar in Chrome app mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, kiosk

Trying to employ kiosk based on Chrome browser. Just Installed Kiosk app extension, everything is fine, but in Chrome's application mode there are no toolbar. I basically need "Back", "Forward", "Home" buttons. Is there any way to enable toolbar in app mode, or add it when extension creates window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigation is not meaningful for Chrome Apps. It is, in fact, [disabled](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated).

So if your app changes state, you need custom controls for that state anyway.

If you have embedded web content in the app in a [`<webview>`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#webview), then you need to make your own custom controls for that. See the [browser app sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webview-samples/browser).